# Via command line: convert (.tif and .pdf) to .jpg or .png

Tags: windows, graphics, image-processing

anyone know a free, stable commandline tool (besides ImageMagick) to convert .tif files and .pdf files to either .jpg or .png?

thanks Michelle

Answer (score 1):

[tiff2png](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/apps/tiff2png.html)

On mac os x:

```
$ brew install tiff2png
$ tiff2png -compression 9 *.tif
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Imagemagick for Windows stuff, but [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) performs well, too.  It looks like it has switches for command-line conversion of image formats, as well. See the "/convert" option.